# Sewer Smell in Sumps

Tags: smell, sump-pump, sewer, septic

I recently bought a house with two sump pumps in the basement. They do their job well despite running every hour or two due to the high clay table in the area. The property also has a septic system, but we will soon (within a week or so) be connecting to the new public sewer.

Last night, I noticed my sump pumps were kicking on very frequently - about every 5 minutes. When I went down to investigate, I was hit with a wall of sewer-gas smell emanating from both sumps. The smell is now taking over the house at night, so I've had to shut off the AC and open the windows. Now, my first assumption is an issue with the septic system. Would it be wise to wait until we connect to public sewer (and the septic is pumped) to verify my theory, or is there something else I should try in the meantime? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you had a lot of rain recently?

Comment: No more than usual. It last rained on Thursday and the sumps started filling yesterday (Monday).

Comment: Are there any floor drains in your basement? Check the traps to see if they still have water in them.

Comment: No, just a perimeter drain that drains into the sumps. That's dry, though. I just got home

Comment: Oops. Premature post. I just got home and while the flow hasn't subsided, the smell has somewhat lessened. I'm thinking about perhaps grabbing some dye to flush down the drain to see if it turns up in the sump. At this point though, I just can't imagine a leaking septic tank causing such a steady flow for so long.